# Getting an error running mongo shell command via bash

Tags: bash, mongodb

I am working on Solaris 10, with `mongo` version `2.0.4` ,

```
{root} #: ./mongo --shell --eval 'use db'
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
fork() available!
connecting to: test
type "help" for help
Tue Sep 20 14:44:22 compile error: (shell eval):1 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
use db
    ^^

{root} #:
```

I have written a script where I was trying to insert a set of files in db:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /test2/sam
for f in *.bin.gz do 
    cd /opt/csw/bin
    ./mongofiles -l /test2/sam/$f -d mahi put $f SUBSTRING=$(echo $f| cut -c11-19) ./mongo << EOF 
    use mahi "db.fs.files.update({\ $filename: \"$f" },{ \$set: {"ROP": \"$SUBSTRING"}})"
EOF
done
```

mahi is the db name; while executing this I'm getting compile error as:

> Tue Sep 20 15:05:40 compile error: (shell):1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token } _ROOT_MO_R,MeContext=CTL01008_celltracefile_3-1378091167645.‌​bin.gz" },{ $set:

Any leads helping me fix the issue is appreciated.

Comment: i have written a script  where i was trying to insert a set of files in db  #!/bin/bash
cd /test2/sam
for f in *.bin.gz
do
cd /opt/csw/bin
./mongofiles -l /test2/sam/$f -d mahi put $f
SUBSTRING=$(echo $f| cut -c11-19)
./mongo << EOF
use mahi
"db.fs.files.update({\ $filename: \"$f" },{ \$set: {"ROP": \"$SUBSTRING"}})"
EOF
done
 mahi is the db name , while executing this m getting compile error as Tue Sep 20 15:05:40 compile error: (shell):1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
_ROOT_MO_R,MeContext=CTL01008_celltracefile_3-1378091167645.bin.gz" },{ $set:

Comment: You should use the [edit] button and ensure the correct test of your script is shown. I had to guess from the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove --shell

From docs

> --shell.    Used in conjunction with a JavaScript file (i.e. ) to continue in the mongoshell after running the JavaScript

Also, 
--eval is only for jscript not for Mongo shell commands. Specify db on cmd line.